# How to get current url query params in ajax request?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I add all current query parameters from current url to a `jquery` `GET` `ajax` request?

```
 $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: "backend/count",
      dataType: 'text',
      success: function (rsp) {
        ...
      }
}
```

Comment: if you mean the query params used for the url of the page currently loaded on window: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/search ... once you've got them you can use them in any way including the chance to append them to the url needed to perform an ajax request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: "backend/count" + window.location.search,
```

Comment: to close the circle you should accept it :D ... after all that's how it goes